# How a skip list is initialized?

Tags: data-structures

I'm reading the [William Pugh's paper about skip-list](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CEcQFjAC&url=http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.85.9211&rep=rep1&type=pdf&ei=HFueT9PaD8ucOr6I8PsB&usg=AFQjCNGaB1pJbYsiO40s6jeKjDlcudGDTA&sig2=2qeuXpTXiYt9VDYMvrLFAA). In section *Initialization* he says:

> An element NIL is given a key greater than any legal key. All levels
>   of all skip lists are terminated with NIL. A new list is initialized
>   so that the level of the list is equal to 1 and all forward pointers
>   of the list’s header point to NIL.

I'm not sure of what he says. I think that he means: Let be *n* the maximum permitted level for each node. So build an header of level *n*. In a first step each level of the header points to NIL. It's right?

Now, when the first node arrives, this will be inserted in a probabilistic way, so its level should be unpredictable. Why he talks of a level 1 list? What I'm missing?

Best regards

MC

Answer (score 1):

I can't read the document, but if I recall correctly, it'd be that `NIL` is an element in the list, and that its `level` is greater than any valid `level` to ensure that it's always the last item. Let's say your levels go from `1` to `3`, then you'd set `NIL`'s level to `4`. When you create a new skip list it should look like this:

```
H = Header
N = Nil
   _    _
4 |H|->|N| 
3 |H|->|N| <- max for normal elements
2 |H|->|N|
1 |H|->|N|
```

After you've added a few elements, you'd have:

```
   _                   _
4 |H|---------------->|N| 
3 |H|-------|B|------>|N|
2 |H|-------|B|->|C|->|N|
1 |H|->|A|->|B|->|C|->|N|
```

Answer (score 1):

The empty list (a new list) should have level 1. More levels are added as needed during insertion (which comes later).

Comment: So first node inserted is always a node with a single level?

Comment: Yes! Also check out this picture from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Skip_list.svg Note that the rightmost element (`10`) have only one level, since there's no need to "leap forward".